# ExtJS 4: How can I get all grid columns in current order?

Tags: extjs

When I use `grid.columns` it returns all columns from grid (visible or not), but it's not in current order..

Then I tried `grid.getView().getGridColumns()` and it returned the columns in current order, but only the visible ones.

How can I get all columns, visible and not visible, in current order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try

```
grid.down('headercontainer').getGridColumns();
```

returns visible and non-visible columns

```
grid.down('headercontainer').getVisibleGridColumns();
```

returns only visible columns

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite problem as I need only the visible ones. For all columns grid.columns seems like the easiest way (since 2.3). I then put them in a map by name because I needed to access row cells:

```
var headerColumns = myGrid.columns;
var headerMap = {};
//put them in a map of name, index
Ext.each(headerColumns, function(headerColumn, i) {
  headerMap[headerColumn.dataIndex] = i;
});
```